# Setting environment variables for dotnetcore Windows service -- process only, not system or user

Tags: .net-core, configuration

Our developers are writing some Windows Services in .NET Core 3.1.

As I understand it, the typical pattern for Core development is to check the DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT variable to switch on different configurations.

For Reasons<sup>TM</sup>, we want to avoid setting system-level or even user-level machine environment variables. Some of the reasons are:

- something else to set up when rolling out a new server
- might want to run different "environments" on the same server -- not for services, maybe, but for other commandline apps

For Kestrel hosted apps launched by IIS, extra environment values can be set in web.config. This can't apply to commandline apps.

What's the best practice for this? Is there a way to set environment variables before launching the executable? Or set environment variables within the process, at startup time, by reading them from a config file?

Other things to mention:

- When we start containerizing things, setting container-level environment variables is obviously the way to go, but for shared Windows servers (actually VMs) like this, we need a different approach.
- We have reviewed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1 . Even though it is targeted at ASP.NET Core and not console/service apps in Core.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Buried in the documentation under [Environment variable configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#environment-variable-configuration-provider) is the following extract:

> The default configuration loads environment variables and command-line arguments prefixed with `DOTNET_`. The `DOTNET_` prefix is used by .NET for [host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host#host-configuration) and [app configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/generic-host#app-configuration), but not for user configuration.

So if you use the command line parameter `--environment Development` that should get transformed into `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT=Development`.  This was tested as working with a .NET 5.0 worker service.

Comment: Just a note on this - this works 100%, but it only works if you use `dotnet` to actually run the worker. If you build a self contained exe that can be run without the `dotnet` command, you will need to find another way. For me, what I ended up doing was just passing in the parameter `EnvironmentName` to the exe and used it from args to get the environment (i.e. `WorkerService.exe Uat`)

Comment: @NewteqDeveloper Not true, works even in exe, as long as you pass command line arguments to CreateDefaultBuilder: `IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>         Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)`

Comment: @Bohdan Ah, I did not realize that step. That was missing. I think it's important to keep in mind that using a variable as input into the `exe` can help if you need to run more than a single dotnet application on the same server.

Comment: @Bohdan - i have an environment variable as DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT on my server and I have created my worker service as windows service. When trying to run/start it, it throws an error, presumably not detecting the hostContext object or the Environment. How do i go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

I've settled on this answer: To all appearances, a .NET core app starting up will not, by default, look at any config files to set environment variables. So, either the code has to set its own environment variables by adding code to do so, or a wrapper app is necessary to set those variables before spawning the app.

Comment: You should be able to pass the configuration on the command line, i.e. `MyService.exe --environment Development`

Comment: This is a very good idea and if you make it an Answer I will accept it.